# backbone.js validation and hyperlink click

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

In the below code i dont see an alert when I click on the hyperlink nor in the case when the text box is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="#" class="but" id="next_btn">Next</a>
<input name="text" class="but" id="newcampaign" />

CM.Views.newCampaign = Backbone.View.extend({

  validate : function () {
    if ($("#newcampaign").val() == "") {
      alert("Enter campaing name");
    }
  },

  initialize : function() {
    _self=this
    this.campaign = new Campaign();
    this.campaign.url='js/editdata.json';
  }, 

  events:{
    'onclick #next_btn': 'submit_form'
  },

  submit_form : function(){
    alert("here");
  },
});
```

Comment: The event is `click`, not `onclick`

Comment: my mistake, what about the validation part?

Comment: I've added a possible validation, please expand your question if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this

```
events:{
  'onclick #next_btn': 'submit_form'
},
```

you should use

```
events:{
  'click #next_btn': 'submit_form'
},
```

since the event name is `click` not `onclick`. Also remember that if you want to change the behaviour of an anchor as you're doing you should call `preventDefault` on the event, like this

```
submit_form : function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("here");
},
```

on the argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

For the validation:

```
events:{
  'click #next_btn': 'validate'
},
validate: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    alert("Enter campaign name");
  } else {
    // you should give the following instruction a url to navigate to
    Backbone.history.navigate(url, true);
  }
},
```

Comment: K i used e.preventdefault with your second solution and it wont resirect if the text box is empty but if the text box is not empty it doesnt route..

Comment: That is because you `preventDefault`ed, you should use `Backbone.history.navigate(url, true)` with the `url` of your choice to navigate away.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone does not have a validation process for Views, you have to run your validation function on your own, maybe from `submit_form`, or use some [plugins](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Extensions,-Plugins,-Resources) for Backbone (like https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms).